# CATIA VBA Measure a user selected line(s)/spline

Tags: vba, catia

I am trying to get the length of user selected lines/splines

This is the code I'm using to have users select their lines:

```
Dim USel As Selection
Dim USelLB
Dim InputObject(0)

InputObject(0) = "AnyObject"
Set USel = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection
Set USelLB = USel

USel.Clear
USelLB.Clear

Linestomeasure = USelLB.SelectElement3(InputObject, "Select objects to list names", True, CATMultiSelTriggWhenUserValidatesSelection, False)
```

`Linestomeasure` is a `public` variable, in the mainsub i've been trying to measure `Linestomeasure` using the following code:

```
Dim pd1 As PartDocument
Dim a As Object
Dim c As Reference

a = TrimLines.Item(1)
c = pd1.Part.CreateReferenceFromObject(a)

Dim Mea1 As Measurable
Dim TheSPAWorkbench As SPAWorkbench
Set TheSPAWorkbench = pd1.GetWorkbench("SPAWorkbench")
Set Mea1 = TheSPAWorkbench.GetMeasurable(c)
```

But when I run the code `a = trimLines.Item(1)` gets highlighted in the debugger with the error message "Object Required".

Does anyone have an idea on how I can change my code so that I can get the length of the line as a variable that I can work with ? Or just a different way to go about what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited answer to reflect comment bellow**

Looks like you are assigning the wrong type of variable to the `USelLB.SelectElement3` and also missunderstanding how it actually works.

The `Selection.SelectElement3` returns a `String` that reflects whether the selection was sucessfull or not.

The `Object` retrieved from the `Selection` is inside the `Selection.Item(Index)`

Your code should be something like this:

```
Dim PD1 as PartDocument
Dim Sel 'as Selection 'Sometimes it is needed to comment the selection to use the .SelectElement3 method
Dim InputObjType(0)
Dim SelectionResult as string    
Dim LineToMeasure as AnyObject    
Dim I as Integer    
Dim SpaWorkbench as SPAWorkbench
Dim Measurable as Measurable

InputObjType(0) = "AnyObject"

'set PD1 = Catia.ActiveDocument
set Sel = PD1.Selection
Set TheSPAWorkbench = pd1.GetWorkbench("SPAWorkbench")    

Sel.Clear
SelectionResult= Sel.SelectElement3(InputObject, "Select objects to list names", True, CATMultiSelTriggWhenUserValidatesSelection, False)

If SelectionResult = "Ok" or SelectionResult = "Normal" then 'Check if user did not cancel the Selection
    For i = 1 to Selection.Count
        Set LineToMeasure = Sel.Item(i).Value
        set Measurable = SpaWorkbench.GetMeasurable(LineToMeasure)

        'Measure whatever you need here.
    Next
End If
```

Keep in mind that using the `AnyObject` type filter may cause the user to select unwanted objects. You shoudl use a more specific filter.

Comment: Did you set `TrimLines` variable properly before using it? The code you posted does not show it.

Comment: Sorry, `TrimLines` is `Linestomeasure` I changed the variable in one when I made the post and not the other.

If I set `TrimLines` as `Public Trimlines` and use `TrimLines = USelLB.SelectElement3(InputObject, "Select objects to list names", True, CATMultiSelTriggWhenUserValidatesSelection, False)` then I get the original error

If I use `Public TrimLines as Selection` and use `Set TrimLines = USelLB.SelectElement3(InputObject, "Select objects to list names", True, CATMultiSelTriggWhenUserValidatesSelection, False)` then I get the "Object Required" error on the SelectElement3 line

Comment: I have just updated my answer.. Please, check it out.

Comment: That worked, THANK YOU! and thanks for explaining how SelectElement works, that makes loads more sense now. Is there a resource that explains how VBA functions and commands work? Like in all my googling the past couple days I couldn't find anything really helpful explaining how selectelement works.

Comment: There is a CATIA API documentation available on your CATIA instalation folder. It may be something like (\code\bin\V5Automation.chm).